# Не понятна работа функции по подбору шаблона перевода строки

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования, replace

Конкретно имеются вопросы по строкам 1  и 2.

В примере ниже функция i18n осуществляет перевод строки.
Она подбирает по строке вида "Hello, ${name}!" шаблон перевода "Привет, {0}!" (где {0} – место для вставки параметра) и возвращает переведённый результат со вставленным именем name:

```js
'use strict';

let messages = {
  "Hello, {0}!": "Привет, {0}!"
};

function i18n(strings, ...values) {
  // По форме строки получим шаблон для поиска в messages
  // На месте каждого из значений будет его номер: {0}, {1}, …
  let pattern = "";
  for(let i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    pattern += strings[i] + '{' + i + '}';
  }
  pattern += strings[strings.length-1];
  // Теперь pattern = "Hello, {0}!"

  let translated = messages[pattern]; // "Привет, {0}!" (1)*

  // Заменит в "Привет, {0}" цифры вида {num} на values[num]
  return translated.replace(/\{(\d)\}/g, (s, num) => values[num]);//(2)*
}

// Пример использования
let name = "Вася";

// Перевести строку
alert( i18n`Hello, ${name}!` ); // Привет, Вася!
```

Comment: _Конкретно имеются вопросы по строкам 1 и 2._ - а что за вопросы-то?

Comment: С первой понятно,непонятно,что в функции replace происодит

Comment: А для чего добавлять последний кусок строки strings[strings.length-1]; ? Без этого строка целой после перебора массива строк и прибавления к переменной pattern будет не полной?

Comment: А ты читал ответ? :-) там понятно написано что приходит в strings, а что в values. Суть в том, что исходный шаблон разбивается на подстроки и значения, который между этими подстроками вставляются. в функции ты собираешь строку заново, подставляя нужные значения. При этом values у тебя всегда на 1 меньше, то есть после цикла вставки всех values, остался последний элемент в strings, которому не соответствует ни одно значение. Иногда он может быть пустой строкой, но в общем случае нет. поэтому его вручную и добавляют в результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем коде используется шаблонная строка, точнее, [теговый шаблон](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B):

> Они позволяют разбирать шаблонные литералы с помощью функции. Первый аргумент такой функции содержит массив строковых значений, а остальные содержат выражения из подстановок. В итоге, функция должна вернуть собранную строку (или что-либо совсем иное).

То есть, значения из массива строк и второго массива логически идут последовательно друг за другом. Например, для строки `Hello, ${"Peter"}, how ${"are you?"}?` будут сформированы такие аргументы:

```
strings = ["Hello, ", ", how ", "?"]
values = ["Peter", "are you"]
```

В текущем случае аргументы такие:

```
strings = ["Hello, "!"]
values = ["Вася"]
```

Получается, что исходный шаблон для перевода потерян. Цикл после строки `let pattern = "";` и до Вашей первой строки как раз его и восстанавливает – собирает части строк из массива `strings` и добавляет скобки с индексами. Получается строка `"Hello, {0}!"`

На самой строке 1 (`let translated = messages[pattern]`) в словаре ищется построенный шаблон и его перевод. Получается строка `"Привет, {0}!"` После, на строке 2, индексы в фигурных скобках перевежённого шаблона заменяются обратно на подставленные значения из вызывающей функции с помощью [лямбды](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) и [регулярного выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). В итоге получается искомое `"Привет, Вася!"`